# How do you use the AES key wrap cipher with the OpenSSL command line utility?

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, cryptography

When you run the command `openssl enc -ciphers` a list of supported ciphers is printed.  In more recent versions of the OpenSSL utility the ciphers -id-aes256-wrap, -id-aes256-wrap-pad, and -aes256-wrap appear in that list.  I believe these are implementations of the AES Key Wrapping algorithms specified in RFC3394, and RFC5649.  When I go to use them to wrap a 256 bit key though as follows I get an error...

```
openssl enc -id-aes256-wrap -in test.key -out test.key.wrp

Error setting cipher id-aes256-wrap
140403454670488:error:0607B0AA:digital envelope routines:EVP_CipherInit_ex:wrap mode not allowed:evp_enc.c:218:
```

When I searched for the error "wrap mode not allowed" I found [this message board text](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2018-May/007998.html) discussing how some special flags need to be set.  But the discussion is in relation to using the openssl library's C API.  Is it possible to use these key wrapping ciphers from the openssl enc utility and if so how?

Comment: The question is off-topic, here. You would want to checkout https://crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a question about using a Linux command line utility not about encryption.  Questions like this are explicitly not appropriate for the crypto stack exchange .

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you running ?

This 
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2485
turned to
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2486

The problem is, it did not work in Feb 2017, unless your openssl version is newer than that and you are in luck, it might work ... but I cannot find an issue where it is reported as fixed so i doubt it even works in the latest and greatest.

In short, congratulations, you have found a bug - I suggest you report it. They have many bugs to squash, if nobody reports this then chances are low they will fix it (why fix a feature nobody uses or complained about).